# Subtraction in Python dataframe but with a logic

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, join, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to convert below input column to output column.

```
ff = pd.DataFrame({'Input':[0,50,0,49,4,100,2,4,1,5,6,3,2],
                   'Output':[0,50,0,49,4,100,98,94,93,88,82,79,77]})
```

Logic:Start subtracting input numbers from 100(whose index is 6)
onwards towards down so we get output table.

```
Example 100-2=98
then 98-4=94
then 94-1=93 and so on
```

What I tried:

I tried to use rolling average but it dint work out, I tried using a loop but not
understanding how to pass index 6 into
the loop as loop starts working from index 0 to do the subtraction but
I want it from index 6.
I also tried some pandas functionality also which dint work

Comment: What is so special about 6? Will you always start from that line?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem, but why not just copying the `Output` column into the 'Input' column?It looks like you already have your output..

Comment: hi there, did any of the answers work?

Answer (score 0):

```
ff = pd.DataFrame({'Input':[0,50,0,49,4,100,2,4,1,5,6,3,2]})
ff['Output'] = ff.Input 
ff.iloc[6:, 1] = 100 - ff.iloc[6:, 0].cumsum()
```

Comment: Right idea, but wrong answer. Must be `ff.iloc[6:, 1] = ff.iloc[5,0] - ff.iloc[6:, 0].cumsum()`.

Comment: Haha I do when I'm on my laptop, posting from phone right now

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do it like this:

```
ff['Output2'] = ff.loc[(ff['Input'] == 100).cummax(), 'Input'].cumsum().mul(-1).add(200)
ff['Output2'] = ff['Output2'].fillna(ff['Input'])
```

Output:

```
    Input  Output  Output2
0       0       0      0.0
1      50      50     50.0
2       0       0      0.0
3      49      49     49.0
4       4       4      4.0
5     100     100    100.0
6       2      98     98.0
7       4      94     94.0
8       1      93     93.0
9       5      88     88.0
10      6      82     82.0
11      3      79     79.0
12      2      77     77.0
```

Maybe a little different way:

```
m = ff['Input'].eq(100).cummax()
ff['Output3'] = ff['Input'].mask(m, 200 - ff.loc[m, 'Input'].cumsum())
```

Output:

```
    Input  Output  Output2  Output3
0       0       0      0.0        0
1      50      50     50.0       50
2       0       0      0.0        0
3      49      49     49.0       49
4       4       4      4.0        4
5     100     100    100.0      100
6       2      98     98.0       98
7       4      94     94.0       94
8       1      93     93.0       93
9       5      88     88.0       88
10      6      82     82.0       82
11      3      79     79.0       79
12      2      77     77.0       77
```

Just showing three different outputs, your expected, my first calculation, and my second calculation.